# snap - cannot update snap-store preview/edge: cannot create symlink when update

Tags: 22.04, snap, snap-store

I saw I can't open my software store and when I tried to update via terminal I saw this error:

cannot update snap namespace: cannot create symlink in "/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids": existing file in the way

I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69134662/cannot-update-snap-namespace-cannot-create-symlink-in-etc-docker-existing-f but that doesn't resolve my problem here.

Someone knows why happen this? What I have to do to fix it?

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 (Gnome desktop)
CPU + GPU = AMD (Amd Ryzer 7 4000 series  & Radeon RX 5600m)

Comment: Are you running in a Docker?

Comment: No, far as I know.

Comment: Why this happens: probably similar to here: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/egl-using-snaps-on-impish-seem-to-be-broken-when-using-the-nvidia-proprietary-driver/25715/14